# Show page number on chapter start pages too

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, page-numbering

Currently the page numbers are missing on pages where a chapter starts. I assume this is a setting inherited by `\pagestyle{scrheadings}`. But how can I add page numbers to chapter start pages too?

```latex
\documentclass[chapterprefix=true, 12pt, a4paper, oneside, parskip=half, listof=totoc, bibliography=totoc, numbers=noendperiod]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark{chapter}
\ihead{\leftmark}
\chead{}
\ohead{\thepage}
\ifoot*{}
\cfoot[\thepage]{}
\cfoot*{}
\ofoot*{}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{One}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Chapter start page header:
[image: Chapter page header]

Default page header:
[image: Default page header]

Comment: Hi, can you modify your MWE to be compilable?

Comment: OK, demo code is now working as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default chapter pages use page style `plain`. `\ihead`, `\ohead` etc. have a optional argument for the content on `plain` pages. If the content is the same on both `plain` and `scrheadings` pages, you can use the starred version, eg `\ohead*{\pagemark}` is a short version of `\ohead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}`.

I would suggest to use `\pagemark` for the page number in header and footer. Then the font element `pagenumber` (default is `\normalfont\normalcolor`) is taken into account.

Using `\clearpairofpagestyles` the predefined content of header and footer for page styles `plain` and `scrheadings` can be removed.

Note that package `scrlayer-scrpage` sets page style `scrheadings` automatically.

For onesided documents option `automark` does the same as `\automark{chapter}`.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[chapterprefix=true,12pt, a4paper, oneside, parskip=half, listof=totoc, bibliography=totoc, numbers=noendperiod]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets page style scrheadings automatically
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\leftmark}
\ohead*{\pagemark}
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{}% default is \normalfont\normalcolor

\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

Additional remarks:

If there should be a headsepline on `plain` pages too, add option `plainheadsepline`.

If you would use `headsepline` as class option, option `headinclude` would be set too (automatically).

After loading `scrlayer-scrpage` page style `plain` is an alias page style of `plain.scrheadings`.

Comment: Well explained, thanks. It's working. I'll do it like this.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the solution. `\ohead` command has `{}` for default pages and `[]` for the chapter start pages. According to the manual it has another meaning but it does what I want:

```latex
\documentclass[chapterprefix=true, 12pt, a4paper, oneside, parskip=half, listof=totoc, bibliography=totoc, numbers=noendperiod]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark{chapter}
\ihead{\leftmark}
\chead{}
\ohead[\thepage]{\thepage} % <- HERE: page number on chapter page and default pages
\ifoot*{}
\cfoot*{}
\ofoot*{}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{One}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is from the documentation.
http://www.pirbot.com/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguide.pdf
and this link:
https://golatex.de/renewcommandchapterpagestyle-t3048.html

```latex
\documentclass[chapterprefix=true, 12pt, a4paper, oneside, parskip=half, listof=totoc, bibliography=totoc, numbers=noendperiod]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark{chapter}
\ihead{\leftmark}
\chead{}
\ohead{\thepage}
\ifoot*{}
\cfoot[\thepage]{}
\cfoot*{}
\ofoot*{}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\renewcommand{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}{
}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{One}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Edit: after comment

[image]

Comment: Thanks, i changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: The `\cfoot` is in the group too, so in the resulting pdf there is no page number in footer. Additionally the OP does not want a page number in footer. Therefore remove `{\cfoot{-{ }\pagemark{ }-}}` too.